# How to Update the value in the json file without changing the file combination in PHP

Tags: php, json

I've started a short time working with php.
I have already written a php code to update the json file,
ut after run the codes, my string of json file format changed and all of the strings set in one line!!

I json file to have the following format in In several lines:

```html
{
"Param": {
"ID":"1",
"status":"ok",
"username":"Rose",
"password":"edition12548",
"Enable":"1"
},
"PRO":
{
"ID":"End",
"Finished":"True"
}
}
```

and use this code for update Enable value:

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("C:\List.json");
$array = json_decode($jsondata, true);
      $array[Param]["Enable"]="2";
    file_put_contents('C:\List2.json', json_encode($array));
```

but the new json file format changed and all strings set in one line:

{"Param":{"ID":"1","status":"ok","username":"Rose","password":"edition12548","Enable":"2"},"PRO":{"ID":"End","Finished":"True"}}

I want to make changes by keeping the format
What are the ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "prettify" the output of the json_encode function you have to add a second parameter to the function that is the "options" parameter. In your case (if I understood correctly) an example of the code you have to use will be:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you want to learn more about other json_encode options you can read this PHP documentation page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php